# Determine if integer contains another integer

Tags: number-theory, integers

Is there a numeric method one can use to determine if a non-negative integer contains another non-negative integer?

For example, the integer 1472 contains 47. (Any number A that is a substring of another number B would be contained by B.)

My specific application is for substring matching within an OpenGL shader, but that shouldn't matter.

I can imagine some algorithmic approaches to this problem, and feel like there could be some clever modulo-related approach to determine if a number contains another number. That said, I haven't cracked this yet.

Any suggestions or hints others can offer would be hugely appreciated! If this question belongs elsewhere please just let me know and I'll move it...

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by contains?  If the integer is -12345, does it contain 234? -234? 123? -12345? 5?

Comment: Good questions. I'm willing to say only positive integers will be part of this system, and containment is just a check whether the sequence of numeric characters in A is also a sequence in B.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a numeric approach? To me this is just a substring matching problem, for which there are [many methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm).

Comment: I'm looking to essentially run this algorithm in a vertex shader within WebGL (subspec of OpenGL ES 2.0), and there are no string types in GLSL (the language used in WebGL shaders)...

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a clever way,
so I'll try brute force.

For any positive integer $n$,
let $nd(n)$ be the number of
digits in $n$
so
$nd(n)
=\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1$.

To see if $n$
is a part of $m$,
check if

$10^{nd(n)}\lfloor \dfrac{m}{10^{k+nd(n)}} \rfloor
=\lfloor \dfrac{m}{10^{k}} \rfloor-n
$
for
$k = 0
$
to $nd(m)-nd(n)-1$.

The left side
is $m$ with the right
$k+nd(n)$ digits deleted
and then shifted left $nd(n)$ digits.

The right side shifts $m$ right $k$ digits
and subtracts $n$.

If the two are the same,
the right $nd(n)$ digits
of $m$ shifted right $k$ digits
match $n$.

If they are never the same,
$n$ never matches $m$.